# navigation drawer icons are not displayed

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer. In the menu, I am trying to use some icons to the items in the menu but they don't appear. it looks like this.

[image]

here is the XML for the menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_overview"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_bell"
            android:title="@string/overview" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_symptoms"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_symptoms"
            android:title="@string/symptoms" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_prevention"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_preventation"
            android:title="@string/prevention" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_treatment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_medicine"
            android:title="@string/treatment" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_statistics"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_statistics"
            android:title="@string/statistics" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_world"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_world_data"
            android:title="World-wide Statistics" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:title="@string/settings" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

all the icons that I am using are svgs and I imported them to android studio as vector assests.
what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I has the same problem. Found out that svg are not usable as icons. I used png and that solved my problem.

Comment: @A_Singh7 You're right svg are not usable as icons, but him said that exported it how a **<vector>**, so this could be used as a icon, if it was processed without any problem and the svg image is really correct. Try to use the icon into any ImageView and see if it appear correctly, try to open the file on Android Studio and see if it shows properly. If not is something wrong with the svg, probably something into svg that is not converted well by the tool.

Comment: I tried png of the same image and it didn't show

Comment: tried t display it in an ImageView and it appeared normally